# GDIPlus DrawImage white color is getting black

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

I'm using GDIPlus to scale image from a buffer.
I'm taking a screenshot of my desktop.
Here is my code:

```
BYTE *Duplication::scaleBuffer(unsigned char *data, int width, int height)
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(width, height, 4 * width, PixelFormat32bppARGB, data);
    INT n_width = mWidthResolution;
    INT n_height = mHeightResolution;
    double ratio = ((double)width) / ((double)height);
    if (width > height) {
        n_height = (double)n_width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        n_width = n_height * ratio;
    }
    Gdiplus::Bitmap newBitmap(n_width, n_height, bitmap.GetPixelFormat());
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(&newBitmap);
    graphics.SetInterpolationMode(Gdiplus::InterpolationModeBilinear);
    graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, 0, 0, n_width, n_height);

    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, newBitmap.GetWidth(), newBitmap.GetHeight());
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
    BYTE *buffer = nullptr;
    if (Gdiplus::Ok == newBitmap.LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, &bitmapData)) {
        int len = bitmapData.Height * std::abs(bitmapData.Stride);
        buffer = new BYTE[len];
        RtlZeroMemory(buffer, len);
        memcpy(buffer, bitmapData.Scan0, len);
        newBitmap.UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

On windows with white background, I got a black background and color is corrupted.. It happens only on some program like "File Browser".. I don't understand why ...

Comment: That's not what I'm using ? Which one precisely ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is the one you're using. What is the purpose of this `LockBits` and `memcpy` code then?

Comment: The problem is likely where you capture the pixel data from the screen.  You're assuming that it's 32-bit RGBA.  I suspect it's 32-bit but without an alpha channel.  Show us the code that does the screen shot, or test the code above with known-good RGBA data.

Comment: LockBits is to retrieve new scaled buffer !
@AdrianMcCarthy I'm using AcquireNextFrame to get the desktop buffer pixels